# Insert into database not fire using Jquery in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2008

its been a whole day trying to short out my problem.
Now i am here..
i am trying to create a student registration page and on submit it should go to next tab..
here is the .aspx and jquery :

```html
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default8.aspx.vb" Inherits="Default8" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .tdText
        {
            font: 12px Verdana;
            color: #333333;
            font-weight: 600;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#<% =txtRmobile.ClientID%>").keydown(function (e) {
                if (e.shiftKey || e.ctrlKey || e.altKey) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                } else {
                    var key = e.keyCode;
                    if (!((key == 8) || (key == 46) || (key >= 35 && key <= 40) || (key >= 48 && key <= 57) || (key >= 96 && key <= 105))) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#<% =btnRsubmit.ClientID%>").click(function () {
                 var uid = $("#<% =txtRmobile.ClientID%>").val();
                 var mob = $("#<% =txtRmobile.ClientID%>").val();
                 var email = $("#<% =txtRemail.ClientID%>").val();
                var dob = $("#<% =txtRdob.ClientID%>").val();
                
                $.ajax({
                    
                     type: "POST",
                     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                     url: "Default8.aspx/InsertData",
                     data: "{'uid':'" + uid + "','mob':'" + mob + "','email':'" + email + "','dob':'" + dob + "'}",
                     dataType: "json",
                     success: function (data) {
                         var obj = data.d;
                         if (obj == 'true') {
                             $("#<% =txtRmobile.ClientID%>").val('');
                             $("#<% =txtRmobile.ClientID%>").val();
                             $("#<% =txtRemail.ClientID%>").val('');
                             $("#<% =txtRdob.ClientID%>").val();
                             //alert("Details Submitted Successfully");
                             enableTab('3');
                             SelectTab('3');
                         }
                     },
                     error: function (result) {
                         alert("Error");
                         return false;
                     }
                 });
             });
         });
     </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <div runat="server">
        <fieldset class="fieldsetAbout" style="margin-left: 10px; width: 95%; text-align: center">
            <legend style="font-size: 20px; font-family: Arial; color: red">CANDIDATE REGISTRATION</legend>
            <table style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: left">
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <table style="width: 100%">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="4" style="font-size: 14px; font-family: Verdana; color: red; width: 100%; height: 100%; text-align: right">
                                            <input type="button" value="IF ALREADY REGISTRED GO TO LOGIN PAGE"
                                                onclick="gotologin();" class="button" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; padding-top: 5px; text-align: right; width: 30%" class="tdtext">Enter Mobile Number:
                                        </td>
                                        <td colspan="1" style="vertical-align: Top; text-align: left; width: 30%" class="tdtext">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtRmobile" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" MaxLength="10"
                                                placeholder="Mobile Number" Width="220px" Style="vertical-align: top"
                                                OnTextChanged="txtRmobile_TextChanged"
                                                AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
                                            <span style="vertical-align: bottom; color: red; font-size: large">*</span>
                                            <td style="vertical-align: middle; padding-top: 5px; text-align: right; width: 5%" class="tdtext">
                                                <asp:Image ID="ImageMmessage" runat="server" Height="17px"
                                                    Style="z-index: 1; left: 445px; top: 138px; height: 20px; width: 24px"
                                                    Width="17px" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding-top: 13px; width: 30%">
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblMmessage" runat="server"
                                                    Style="z-index: 1; left: 474px; top: 138px; height: 19px; width: 203px"
                                                    Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                                            </td>

                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; padding-bottom: 15px; text-align: right; width: 30%" class="tdtext">Enter Email ID:
                                        </td>
                                        <td colspan="1" style="vertical-align: Top; text-align: left" class="tdtext">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtRemail" runat="server" CssClass="textbox"
                                                placeholder="E-Mail" Width="220px" OnTextChanged="txtRemail_TextChanged"
                                                AutoPostBack="True" />
                                            <span style="vertical-align: bottom; color: red; font-size: large">*</span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; padding-top: 5px; text-align: right; width: 5%" class="tdtext">
                                            <asp:Image ID="ImageEmessage" runat="server" Height="17px"
                                                Style="z-index: 1; left: 445px; top: 138px; height: 20px; width: 24px"
                                                Width="17px" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td colspan="1" style="text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding-top: 13px; width: 30%">
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblEmessage" runat="server"
                                                Style="z-index: 1; left: 474px; top: 138px; height: 19px; width: 203px"
                                                Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: right; width: 40%" class="tdtext">Date of Birth (dd/MM/yyyy) :
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="vertical-align: Top; text-align: left" class="tdtext">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtRdob" runat="server" CssClass="textbox"
                                                placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" Width="150px" Style="float: left" />
                                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" ImageUrl="~/Images/Calendar.png"
                                                ImageAlign="Left" AlternateText="Click here to display calendar"
                                                runat="server" Style="vertical-align: middle; padding-top: 6px" />
                                            <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" PopupButtonID="ImageButton1" runat="server"
                                                TargetControlID="txtRdob" Format="dd/MM/yyyy">
                                            </asp:CalendarExtender>
                                            <span style="vertical-align: top; color: red; font-size: large">*</span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td colspan="3" style="text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding-top: 13px; width: 30%">
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Style="vertical-align: top"></asp:Label>
                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"
                                                ControlToValidate="txtRemail" Display="Dynamic" CssClass="ErrorMsg"
                                                ErrorMessage="Required" ValidationGroup="reg" ForeColor="Maroon" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="4" style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center">
                                            <input id="btnRsubmit" runat="server" type="button" value="  REGISTER  "
                                                class="button" style="Height: 40px; Width: 200px" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; color: red; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 14px" colspan="4">
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblmsg" runat="server"></asp:Label>

                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="4" style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: right; font-family: Forte" class="tdtext">
                                            <span style="color: red; font-size: larger">*</span> Mandatory fields
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

and here is my vb code :

```
<WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethod()> _
Public Shared Function InsertData(ByVal uid As String, ByVal mob As String, ByVal email As String, ByVal dob As String) As String
    Dim msg As String = String.Empty
    Dim strConnString As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("kckcmsDB").ConnectionString
    Using con As New SqlConnection(strConnString)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("insert into sturegI(uid,mobile,email,dob) VALUES(@uid, " _
                                    & " @mobile,@email,@dob)", con)
            con.Open()
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uid", uid)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobile", mob)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", dob)
            Dim i As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()
            If i = 1 Then
                msg = "true"
            Else
                msg = "false"
            End If
        End Using
    End Using
    Return msg
End Function
```

In ViewPageSource it showing :

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_btnRsubmit").click(function () {
                 var uid = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtRmobile").val();
                 var mob = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtRmobile").val();
                 var email = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtRemail").val();
                var dob = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtRdob").val();
                $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                     url: "Default8.aspx/InsertData",
                     data: "{'uid':'" + uid + "','mob':'" + mob + "','email':'" + email + "','dob':'" + dob + "'}",
                     dataType: "json",
                     success: function (data) {
                         var obj = data.d;
                         if (obj == 'true') {
                             $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtRmobile").val('');
                             $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtRmobile").val();
                             $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtRemail").val('');
                             $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtRdob").val();
                             //alert("Details Submitted Successfully");
                             enableTab('3');
                             SelectTab('3');
                         }
                     },
                     error: function (result) {
                         alert("Error");
                         return false;
                     }
                 });
             });
         });
     </script>
```

its not firing as i wish.
please help.....

Comment: Can you please check whether that web method is called or not? Please try to put break point and make sure, it called. Let me know

Comment: Thanks i solved it....("_")